# How to install Ubuntu on a USB drive ext4 partition?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, usb-drive, bootable

I have a **32GB** USB drive with 2 partitions,

**Partition 1**:  `FAT32` used as storage

**Partition 2**:  `ext4` intended to be a *bootable* live **Ubuntu 15.04**.

How can I install the Ubuntu ISO file to the `ext4` partition on the USB drive and make it bootable?

I tried booting **DamnSmallLinux** and **DSL-N** from another **512MB** USB drive I have but couldn't find how to make this work.

I'm running Windows 7 on desktop PC and OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 on laptop.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Do you want to _install_ Ubuntu on USB or just _write_ Ubuntu ISO on USB (create _bootable installation_ usb)?

Comment: I want to _install_ Ubuntu on USB ext4 partition, not just copy the ISO file. Since Windows can't see more than the first partition on the USB drive can't get this to work with Unetbootin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if I get you right `dd` is what you need (comes with OS X). You can create bootable USB with the following command:

```
dd if=/path/to/your/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/xxx bs=4M
```

(*Make sure you saved all necessary data from USB*)

Replace *xxx* in */dev/xxx* with your USB device. You can list devices with `diskutil list` command to find out which one is your USB.

After following this steps you will get bootable USB with Ubuntu and some unallocated free space. So you will be able to boot from it and create some additional partitions on it with GParted.

If you want to *install* Ubuntu on your USB you should create bootable USB first anyway. Then you can boot from it and install Ubuntu on *another USB drive* following any Ubuntu installation tutorial on youtube.

Comment: I'll try this when I'm home, but without any further software OS X is not able to deal with `ext4` file systems. But I don't mind either having both partitions as `FAT32`

Comment: @fulanito, `dd` doesn't need OS X to deal with Ext4. I have managed to create bootable Ubuntu USB on Windows with this utility. It doesn't come with Windows by default but you can get it with Cygwin.

Comment: With Cygwin I used `dd if=/cygdrive/c/Users/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M` and could successfully boot Ubuntu from the 32GB USB drive. I tryed partitioning with _GParted_ both from this Ubuntu drive and from the 512MB USB drive where I installed _GParted live_, but I can't create a partition on the unallocated space because **it is not possible to create more than 1 primary partition**

Comment: I used `cat /proc/partitions` to figure out what /dev/sdx device my USB drive was

Comment: GParted reports **The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes** If I ignore it GParted shows following partitions: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/XhAUEOu.png?1)

Comment: And I get `it is not possible to create more than 1 primary partition` when trying to create a partition on unallocated space (116.2GB), which is not the right size, since the USB drive is 32GB

Answer (score 0):

Use Rufus to make an Ubuntu bootable (say) on an 8GB USB drive, from your downloaded disk image (iso) on your hard drive. Then use this to install Ubuntu on your 32GB USB, which you would then set as first boot in the boot sequence in your BIOS/UEFi.